# Create additional TAB Bar Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5

I have an application with 3 tab controllers the initial two are from default, i have added the 3rd customized it to have all buttons, background images etc through storyboard functionality. But i am having trouble linking that storyboard to the .h and .m files which i have created for it. Does anyone have a breakdown in XCODE 5 with storyboard on the breakdown of adding specifically tab bar controllers to the initial project. I have found table view controllers but the build out was different.

Comment: I assume that you mean 1 UITabBarController with 3 UIViewControllers? Also, are you familiar with the document outline in storyboard?

Comment: Did my answer help?  You should let others know if this helped or not so others can be helped as well, or have someone give a better answer.

Comment: In fact you should at least accept some of the responses you have gotten on your questions or no one will help you out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the storyboard what .h and .m file it needs to be linked to.  On the storyboard select the third tab bar view controller so that it is highlighted.  Now go over to the right hand side of the screen.  Under the identity inspector you can select the class for your view controller.

[image]

It is the highlighted blue icon in the second row of icons.  Then you can select the Class of the view controller in the Class pull down menu.  Whatever you called your .h and .m files, they will appear in the drop down menu.  Select it, then you will be able to control drag from your storyboard to either .h or .m.

Don't forget to select the view controller as in the picture below.

[image]